# Setting variable values on a component that is passed to a service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service that's trying to hydrate values of a given component. Basic functionality:

1. Service will accept a component into its method
2. Do an HTTP request to retrieve data
3. Update @Input variables of the component once data resolves

I wrote some pseudo code below to elaborate what I'm trying to do. Is this possible to do?

Service method:

```js
  public mapTo(component: any): void {
    httpCall.then(result => {
      component.inputVariable = result.data;
    });
  }
```

Component:

```js
export SomeComponent {
  @Input() inputVariable = null; // expecting this to be updated by the service
  constructor(private modelService: ModelService) {
    this.modelService.mapTo(SomeComponent);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's completely backwards. The service should expose the data to the component, not the other way around.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Im actually trying to recreate another implementation(AEM Model manager to be specific) in-house. So I would actually have to do the anti-pattern in this case.

Comment: Do you? What you describe could just as well be achieved by having a parent subscribe to the service and setting the input on a child when it arrives. [Edit] to expand on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a little bit antipattern in Angular world.

```
  public mapTo(component: any): Observable<any>{
    return httpCall.pipe(result => {
      map(result => result.data)
    });
  }
```

and on the component side:

```
SomeComponent {
  inputVariable = null; // expecting this to be updated by the service
  constructor(private modelService: ModelService) {
    this.modelService.mapTo().subscribe(result => this.inputVariable = result);
  }
}
```

If that's not possible, you can try to inject component instance to the service. So in your service file

**xxxxx.service.ts**

```
Injectable()
export class Myservice{
 constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => SaveComponent)) saveComponent){}

 public mapTo(): Observable<any>{
    return httpCall.pipe(result => {
      map(result => this.saveComponent.inputVariable = result.data)
    });
  }
}
```

**v3 - pass the component instance**

Service method:

```
  public mapTo(component: any): void {
    httpCall.then(result => {
      component.inputVariable = result.data;
    });
  }
```

Component:

```
export SomeComponent {
  @Input() inputVariable = null; // expecting this to be updated by the service
  constructor(private modelService: ModelService) {
    this.modelService.mapTo(this);
  }
}
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hkwj81?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhi.component.ts

Comment: Yea I have it working this way but Im actually trying to recreate another implementation(AEM Model manager to be specific) in-house. So I would actually have to do the anti-pattern in this case.

Comment: Hello, I edited my solution in your needs. Can you please try this?

Comment: If edited version doesn't work can you please provide minimal reproducable example on Stackblitz? I guess we can find you a solution by creating the component dynamically also.

Comment: Im getting a `Cannot find name 'SaveComponent'` error for the name in constructor. Let me try and create a stackblitz

Comment: Here's the stackblitz: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bm8kuv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodel.service.ts

Comment: Hello, I updated the answer, also attaching a working Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hkwj81?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhi.component.ts